# HTML Dropdown menu transparent

Tags: html, css

I am currentry writing HTML code for my website, and I've run into a problem, whenever I enable the layout, the dropdown menu becomes transparent
My CSS file is not causing the problem, I tested it several times!
(Please ignore foreign language)

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Kezdőlap</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">Hírek</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="contact.html">Kapcsolat</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Szervereink</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">TeamSpeak 3</a>
      <a href="#">CS:S</a>
      <a href="#">Klán szerverek</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If I make the following code comment, the dropdown menu starts working again, but If I don't it simply goes transparent!

```
<div class="right">
<h1>Legújabb Hírek</h1>
<p>Counter Strike:Source</p>
<p>A CS:S szerverünk most esett át egy nagy frissítésen! SaySounds és RoundEndSounds</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="news.html">Hírek oldal</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
<h1>Köszöntelek a Fluffy Killers Weboldalán!</h1>
<p>A csapatunk nagyon kicsi, és tanulóképes! A csapatunk, Source Engines szervereket hostol, configol, Versenyszerűen játszunk! Csatlakozhatsz a kis csapatunkhoz a Steam csoportunkon keresztül!</p>
<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/FlaffahKallars">Fluffy Killers Steam Csoport</a>
```

NOTES: Class Main is the content of the site, Class Right is a sidebar

Sidebar and Main classes

```
.right {
    position:absolute;
    right: 100px; top:50px; bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    left:10px; top:50px; right:100px; bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: is this the only css?

Comment: try closing your inline style of float:right.  Should read float:right;

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra Do you need the full css? Because it is a nightmare, I'm a newbie

Comment: @KillerDoge your full css would probably help -- Opening up a jsfiddle may be a nice idea too

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/upburnpj/

Comment: @SpencerRohan Here is the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5rm5L1gb/

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra I commented with the full JSfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't that it's transparent, the issue is that the .main and .right sections are positioned absolutely. Try removing position:absolute in these sections - and using margin-top or padding-top in it's place.

```
.right {
  float:right;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.main {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Look into position absolute and position relative properties -- once you master those, you'll be very unstoppable.

Comment: @KillerDoge great! Also, I know you are newbie - but look into something like twitter bootstrap, it comes with a lot of stuff out of the box.  Unless you are wanting to get your feet wet and just build from scratch.  http://getbootstrap.com/